# Extension of embedding from a compact submanifold into $\mathbb R^{n}$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, compact-manifolds

1. Suppose $M$ is a manifold, $N$ is a compact submanifold(with non-empty boundary) of same dimension, $f:N\rightarrow\mathbb R^{n}$ is an embedding into sufficiently-high-dimensional Euclidean space. Under what extra assumptions can we find an extension of $f$ to the whole $M$?
2. A possibly relative question: with $M$ and $N$ same as above, suppose in the following diagram $i$ is inclusion, $f$ and $g$ are embeddings. When is there an embedding $j$ that makes the diagram commute?

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    N @>\displaystyle i>> M\\
    @V \displaystyle f V V\# @VV \displaystyle g V\\
    \mathbb R^{n} @>>\displaystyle j> \mathbb R^{n}
    \end{CD}

Comment: I assume $N$ is a manifold with boundary? Otherwise the only cases of a submanifold of the same dimension are $M=N$ or $M$ is not connected and $N$ is one or several of the connected components.

Comment: It's so vague question. I mean everything can always locally embedded inside $R^n$. But unless you specified what manifold M and N you are interested and what kind of embedding we are talking its next to impossible to have an answer. For example take an nbd of  arbitrat complicated knot in M and embed it  as an unknot...

Comment: @Anubhav Mukherjee I know it is vague, so I am looking for advice for "extra assumptions"......You may assume M is also compact or something about the boundary if you like. Please forgive my ignorance, do you mean in your example the embedding cannot be extended?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, even if it might be difficult to answer. For example the unit disk embeds in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The unit disk can be taken to be N for any 2-manifold M. So let's pick something that won't work: the Klein bottle.